# Does there exist a complete English translation of Narasimha Tapaniya Upanishad?

Tags: upanishads, translation-request, resource

Is there a complete English translation of the Narasimha Tapaniya Upanishad available online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find English translation of all the 108 Upanishads at [Vedanta Spiritual Library](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads/).

Nrisimha Tapini Upanishad belongs to Atharva Veda, here are links to the related Upanishads you might be looking for:

- [Nrisimha Poorva Tapaniya Upanishad](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-atharva-veda/nrisimha-poorva-tapaniya-upanishad/)
- [Nrisimha Uttara Tapaniya Upanishad](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-atharva-veda/nrisimha-uttara-tapaniya-upanishad/)

You can [get/download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_niu9hGiD5QbUpXSzJEUGRhLUk/view) all the Upanishads related to AtharvaVeda in a portable document format.

You may also find it on [vedarahasya.net](http://www.vedarahasya.net/nrisimha.htm).

Answer (score 2):

[**Google book on Uttara and Poorva Nrisimha Tapaniya Upanishats**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XYepeIGUY0gC&pg=PA825&lpg=PA825&dq=This+syllable+is+the+whole+world.+Its+explanation+is+as+follows:+The+past,+the+present+and+the+future,+all+this+is+the+sound+Om.+And+besides,+what+still+lies+beyond+the+three+times,&source=bl&ots=TKiU0ORc0o&sig=nlmB_Oc4uexlK_kQpPA0f2yBT1Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizzsLwnKXXAhVTQLwKHcTODVoQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=This%20syllable%20is%20the%20whole%20world.%20Its%20explanation%20is%20as%20follows%3A%20The%20past%2C%20the%20present%20and%20the%20future%2C%20all%20this%20is%20the%20sound%20Om.%20And%20besides%2C%20what%20still%20lies%20beyond%20the%20three%20times%2C&f=false)

Translation of Nrisimha Tapaniya Upanishat Uttara and Purva both on this website- [**Nrisimha Uttara and Purva Tapaneeya Upanishat**](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/vedicsection/upanishads/nrisimhapurva.asp)